# Pass value from promise to variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, vue.js, promise

I tried to return the value from a Promise and assign it to a local variable inside the function, but the Promise gets fired at last.

The function (which will get fired in Vue.js `mounted()`):

```
getPriceForYesterday(){
    let yesterdayUSD = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.cryptos.length; i++) {
        let cryptoName = this.cryptos[i].title;
        let timestamp = new Date(this.cryptos[i].purchaseDate);
        timestamp.setDate(timestamp.getDate() - 1);
        timestamp = timestamp.toISOString();

        let priceYesterday = getPriceForTimestamp(cryptoName, timestamp);
        Promise.all([priceYesterday]).then((values) => {
            console.log("values", values)
            yesterdayUSD.push(values[0]);
        }).catch(e => console.error(e));

    }
    console.log("yesterdayUSD", yesterdayUSD);
    console.log("yesterdayUSD[0]", yesterdayUSD[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
yesterdayUSD []
yesterdayUSD[0] undefined
values [13308.06]
values [1278.69]
```

I want to use `yesterdayUSD` to compare it with a local storage value and then return the "result" of the comparison to the vue data.

Comment: You have to wait that all promises are resolved to do this comparison. This is because promises are asynchronous. You can, too, rewrite or code and use ES6's async feature.

Comment: Can you tell me how to wait for all resolved promises?
I guess I have to rewrite `getPriceForTimestamp(cryptoName, timestamp)` also in ES6 because I am using Promises for it too.

Comment: You don't have to use ES6 to deal with this. I have posted an answer.

Comment: Can you be more precise on the issue. Is that an issue with the UI showing undefine value ? Which in that case you could always use `v-show` / `v-if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're not seeing anything when trying to write out yesterdayUSD is because the promises are executing asynchronously and they're not complete before reaching the lines where you use console.log();

I'm going to assume that you meant to use Promise.All() to wait for all of the promises to complete because that's typically what it is used for. I rewrote your example to populate an array of promises and then wait after they all resolve before writing out the values in yesterdayUSD. That should at least allow you to print out the values after all of the promises complete.

```
getPriceForYesterday(){
    let yesterdayUSD = [];
    let promises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.cryptos.length; i++) {
        let cryptoName = this.cryptos[i].title;
        let timestamp = new Date(this.cryptos[i].purchaseDate);
        timestamp.setDate(timestamp.getDate() - 1);
        timestamp = timestamp.toISOString();

        let priceYesterday = getPriceForTimestamp(cryptoName, timestamp)
            .then((values) => {
                console.log("values", values)
                yesterdayUSD.push(values[0]);
            })
            .catch(e => console.error(e));

        promises.push(priceYesterday);
    }

    Promise.all(promises).finally(() => {
        console.log("yesterdayUSD", yesterdayUSD);
        console.log("yesterdayUSD[0]", yesterdayUSD[0]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Any idea why the console.logs for yesterdayUSD and yesterdayUSD[0] return "undefined" inside the Promise.finally?

Comment: It shouldn't be undefined. Even if it was executing before the promises finished, yesterdayUSD should at least be an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can rewrite this method/function to return a promise, too

```
getPriceForYesterday(){
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        let yesterdayUSD = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.cryptos.length; i++) {
            let cryptoName = this.cryptos[i].title;
            let timestamp = new Date(this.cryptos[i].purchaseDate);
            timestamp.setDate(timestamp.getDate() - 1);
            timestamp = timestamp.toISOString();

            let priceYesterday = getPriceForTimestamp(cryptoName, timestamp);
            Promise.all([priceYesterday])
            .then((values) => {
                yesterdayUSD.push(values[0]);
            })
            .then( () => {
                resolve(yesterdayUSD)
            })

        }
    })
}
```

and then use it in the  mount() method

```
mount() {
   ...
   getPriceForYesterday().then( yesterdayUSDArray => {
      //do something with this yesterdayUSDArray
   })
}
```

Comment: Can I use it in the function `getPriceForYesterday()` too or do I really need to have it in the mount() method? So after "return new Promise..".

Comment: I really don't know, I have just written this in the mount() because you have said in your question that this function is fired in a mount() method from a Vue's component. You should rewrite it, or place it, wherever is the best for your code.

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/markusdanek/crypto-portfolio/blob/master/src/components/Main.vue#L115

Comment: There is no reference of `yesterdayUSD` outside of the `getPriceForYesterday()` function (which does not make lot of sens) so what is the point. Yes please be more clear in the question.